# Print list under list in java

Tags: java, list

My model class is:

```
public class AreawiseSales{  
    private String location;
    private List<Integer> areaCode;
    private List<String> areaDescription;
    //getter setters are there
}
```

I have added values in this class object now I want to print the values like:

```
LOC     AREA    Description
 1        2         3
          21        31
          22        32
```

My controller is:

```
List<AreawiseSales> listOLists = new ArrayList<AreawiseSales>();

String locationCode="01";

List<Integer> areaCode = new ArrayList<Integer>();
areaCode.add(02);
areaCode.add(04);
areaCode.add(07);

List<String> areaDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
areaDescription.add("Tejgaon/Mohakhali");
areaDescription.add("Mirpur");
areaDescription.add("Shyampur");
```

How can I print these values?

Comment: override `toString()` method for `AreawiseSalesfor` class and then go through each item in the list of AreawiseSales to print it.

Comment: maybe call printf in a loop?

Comment: can i set this---> private String location;
    private List<Integer> areaCode;
    private List<String> areaDescription;  ----any other technique like nested class or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int len = Math.max(listOLists.size(), Math.max(areaCode.size(), areaDescription.size()));
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%10s", (i < listOLists.size()) ? listOLists.get(i) : "");
    System.out.printf(" %10s", (i < areaCode.size()) ? areaCode.get(i) : "");
    System.out.printf(" %30s", (i < areaDescription.size()) ? areaDescription.get(i) : "");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Reference readings:

- http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/
- http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

It will print something like:

```
01         2             Tejgaon/Mohakhali
           4                        Mirpur
           7                      Shyampur
```